# Error sending message using mu4e and password aplication gmail

Tags: mu4e

Im trying to send a message in mu4e, gmail account and 2 pass authentication activated with aplication pass.

My error message is:

> Sending via mail...
> smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at
> 534 5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor az2-20020a05600c600200b003942a244f47sm3531014wmb.32 - gsmtp in response to AUTH
> user-error: Minibuffer window is not active

my offlineimapsrc is:

```
[general]
# List of accounts to be synced, separated by a comma.
accounts = Gmail
maxsyncaccounts = 3
# starttls = yes

[Account Gmail]
# Identifier for the local repository; e.g. the maildir to be synced via IMAP.
localrepository = Gmail-local
# Identifier for the remote repository; i.e. the actual IMAP, usually non-local.
remoterepository = Gmail-remote


[Repository Gmail-local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/Maildir

[Repository Gmail-remote]
type = IMAP
remotehost = imap.gmail.com
remoteuser = lewosky@gmail.com
# my aplication pass
remotepass = zzzjgizelgoutzzz
ssl = yes
maxconnections = 1
realdelete = no
ssl_version=tls1_2

folderfilter = lambda foldername: foldername in ['INBOX', 'Dev']
# Necessary as of OfflineIMAP 6.5.4
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

and mbsync:

```
#!/bin/bash
IMAPAccount gmail
Host imap.gmail.com
User lewosky@gmail.com
Pass zzzjgizelgoutzzz
SSLType IMAPS

SSLVersions TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
AuthMechs login
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

IMAPStore gmail-remote
Account gmail

MaildirStore gmail-local
Subfolders Verbatim
Path ~/Maildir/
Inbox ~/Maildir/INBOX

Channel gmail
Master :gmail-remote:
Slave :gmail-local:
Patterns * ![Gmail]* "[Gmail]/Sent Mail" "[Gmail]/Starred" "[Gmail]/All Mail" "[Gmail]/Trash"
Create Both
Expunge Both
SyncState *
```

Somebody see anything?

Comment: I thought the error message was clear? You are supposed to have two-step authentication set up, so you should be using the app password instead of the password for your Google account.

Comment: I have it in 2 steps and with an application password. And it does not recognize me, it seems that it rejects the authentication due to lack of security